# Too Many Files In Debian Linux Folder?

Tags: linux, debian

I've been using an external USB drive on a Debian server for backup.  The drive is formatted as NTFS and mounted with ntsfmount.  This was working fine, but I was filling up a directory with lots of files.  Eventually the backup failed.  When I then tried to look at the directory using ls it reported:

```
ls: reading directory .: Numerical result out of range
```

Looking in syslog, I also saw this:

> Sep 23 07:35:31 tosh ntfsmount[28040]: Failed to read index block: Numerical result out of range.

Is this simply that I've reached the upper limit of number of files in a directory?  If so, is there any way to extend the number of allowed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to format this drive with a native Linux filesystem like [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) if you wish to continue using it for backups of a Linux server.

The `ntfsmount` is not meant to be used the way you're using it. You've reached one of its limitations.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to do as you say and reformat as ext3.